# How do I change the save location of an altered PDF using PyPDF2

Tags: python

I need to change the location that the output file is saved. Currently the save location is wherever the application is located. I would like to change it to the user's desktop.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader as PdfFileReader, PdfWriter as PdfFileWriter

filename = askopenfilename() 
packet.seek(0)
new_pdf = PdfFileReader(packet)
existing_pdf = PdfFileReader(open(filename, "rb"))
output = PdfFileWriter()
page = existing_pdf.getPage(0)
page.mergePage(new_pdf.getPage(0))
output.addPage(page)
name = (os.path.basename(filename))
name = name[:-4]
outputStream = open(name + "-CARB.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the **name** in your code to the path you want to save

Basically in below statement you can specify where you want to save the file.
For example:

```
outputStream = open("C:\\Users\\<<USERNAME>>\\Desktop\\" + "-CARB.pdf", "wb")
```

Comment: This Worked! I had to add name to use the input filename as the output filename, like this: outputStream = open("C:\\Users\\<<<USERNAME>>>\\Desktop\\" + name + "-CARB.pdf", "wb")

Comment: Good. Nice to hear that.